# Mysql Having doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I have two tables. (MySQL database)
Events:

```
id | title | ...
```

Event_participate:

```
event_id | user_id | confirmed
```

`confirmed` is 0/1 column. I want to find events which are participated by specified user. My SQL query is:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(SUM(ep.confirmed), 0) AS count_members 
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN event_participate ep ON e.id = ep.event_id
GROUP BY ep.event_id
HAVING (
ep.user_id = 6
)
```

I have to use having clasule because I want to expand this query.
I have result of 5 events but when I query this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `event_participate` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 6
```

I have 7 records. How is that possible?

I have edited structure of second table (event_participate) - it helps you understand why I want to use `having` clausule. When I use `WHERE` I will always get 1 in count_members.

EDIT:
My aim is to get events which are participated by specific user and I want to know how many users are already participate these events.

e.g. user id=6 participate one event of id=1. But there are 3 other users which participate event id=1. So I should get one event and in column count_members I should get `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your having clause to a where clause.  The having clause is not using the group-by columns or aggregations, so it is doing "any(user_id) = 6".

```
SELECT *
FROM event e LEFT JOIN event_participate ep ON e.id = ep.event_id
WHERE ep.user_id = 6
GROUP BY ep.event_id
```

Based on your edit, I think you want something like:

```
SELECT ep.event_id, COALESCE(SUM(ep.confirmed), 0) AS count_members
FROM event e LEFT JOIN event_participate ep ON e.id = ep.event_id
GROUP BY ep.event_id 
HAVING max(case when ep.user_id = 6 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

You are trying to restrict the population to events that have at least one user_id = 6, while still counting all the other members.

Comment: You should provide an example of input data and what you want to produce.  I don't think it is clear from the way your question is posed.

Answer (score 0):

Try start with this:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM event e 
INNER JOIN event_participate ep 
    ON e.id = ep.event_id AND ep.user_id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I try fix your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN event_participate ep ON e.id = ep.event_id
GROUP BY ep.event_id, ep.user_id
HAVING (
ep.user_id = 6
)
```

Note that the GROUP BY clause in this query is redundant, and HAVING can be replaced to WHERE

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find events which are participated by specified user.

```
SELECT e.title 
FROM event e
  JOIN event_participate ep ON e.id = ep.event_id
WHERE
  ep.user_id = 6;
```

No need to use the `GROUP BY` clause. You are not aggregating any data.